# How can I set feature flags of a transitive dependency?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo, cargo-features

Suppose I want to install the following dependency in my project:

```ini
[dependencies]
multi-party-ecdsa = { git = "https://github.com/ZenGo-X/multi-party-ecdsa.git", rev = "3e711c792db06aaeeac5694b137d24f7551069d1"}
```

which builds it with `cargo build` command.
I would like this instead: `cargo build --no-default-features --features curv-kzen/num-bigint`. Is it possible without doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ini
[dependencies]
multi-party-ecdsa = { git = "https://github.com/zengo-x/multi-party-ecdsa.git", rev = "3e711c792db06aaeeac5694b137d24f7551069d1", default-features = false }
curv-kzen = { version = "*", default-features = false, features = ["num-bigint"] }
```

This should work.

Comment: It results in Cargo.toml parsing error, `feature "curv-kzen/num-bigint" in dependency "multi-party-ecdsa" is not allowed to contain slashes`.

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake on my part. I fixed it now. The "*" tells it to use whatever version the other dependencies are already using and then sets the `num-bigint` feature of `curv-kzen`.